# Keycloak SSL behind httpd reverse proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, keycloak

I have Keycloak server behind a reverse proxy (httpd). Now I want to configure client certificate authentication?

Is this possible to achieve with Apache's reverse proxy, to somehow pass handshake requests (to proxy Transport layer messages)?

If not, what would be the solution?

Comment: IMHO that is a case for load balancing (tcp level) not for the proxying (http level).

Comment: What do you mean by that? I would like proxy but with this capability. If load balancer can provide me with this, and if it can enable me to put some frontend deployments on it, then that solves my problem.